# UIPageControl voiceover issue

Tags: ios, accessibility, uipagecontrol, voiceover

I have a UIPageControl in my app's onboarding process. Its purpose is not to change pages manually but as an indication of the user's process through the whole onboarding. (There's no swiping gestures right now)

Everything looks fine, but VoiceOver lets the user increment or decrement the control, and says it can be changed (it seems to keep `.adjustable` as a trait). I don't want that behaviour. I just want VoiceOver to read "Page 1 of 3". I disabled it, changed its accessibilityTraits and it doesn't affect VoiceOver.

Here is some code.

```
    /// hard coded values for the example:
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
    pageControl.currentPage = 1
    pageControl.isEnabled = false
    pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    pageControl.accessibilityTraits = .none
```

I have created a [test project on github](https://github.com/leblancF/PageControlAccessibility) for a more complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get your purpose is to **subclass** `UIpageControl` and **override** the `accessibiliTraits` property as follows:

```
class MyPageControl: UIPageControl {

    override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
        get{
            return .none
        }
        set{}
    }
}
```

Define your pageControl element as `MyPageControl` to get the desired result.

Comment: This way works (in regard for my question and the gesture), but the accessibilityTrait .none still let the user double-tap on the control to change it. The accessibilityTrait .notEnabled disables the control completely (which was what I was looking for), but VoiceOver says that it's disabled. This solution will be good enough for me at this time. Thanks!

Comment: @invalidArgument : maybe the best solution is to create your own accessibility element to get exactly this behavior ?